# How to read window content (using accessibilityService) in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, service

I want functionality similar to `Voodoo App` and `MySmartPrice` offers.
(screenshot)
[MySmartPrice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mATGE.png)
Now what they do

`Step 1:` When we open the `Voodoo App` for the first time they show a small tutorial. At the end of tutorial there is a `"Activate Now"` button which when pressed take us to `Accessibility` settings screen.

`Step 2:` In `Accessibility Screen` it further guides how to find and unable the `Voodoo Service`.

`Step 3:` When we enable it, it further ask to grant `"Observe Your Action" and "Retrieve Window Content"` permissions.

`Step 4:` Once we are done granting `permissions` on `accessibility` screen, and move to some shopping app or access `shopping` site via `browser` and reach product page a voodoo floating button pops up automatically.

`Step 5:` Once we click on it, it shows the price of `same/related/similar` products available on other apps or website so that user can check for best deal available.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKTK1.png)

Now what I want y:

How I can show my help `UI` over `Accessibility` screen and product detail page.

How to detect when a product page is there on screen and to evoke my floating button.

How to fetch name of product shown on screen.

How to `restrict` this screen reading `functionality` for some apps only? (as I don't want to end up in some copyright issue)

Is there any tutorial which can help me out? Although I had already tried on Google for any direct tutorial and didn't got any success.